# Is a specific Doctype ever required?

Tags: html, validation, markup

Topic title is the question really. Is a specific DocType ever required? If so, in what situation(s)?

I'm designing a jQuery slideshow script for a Wordpress plugin with quite a large user base. As a result, it needs to be designed to work with a lot of use cases. I'm trying to decide if I should go with using data attributes, or informative classes for Javascript reference only ('js-transition-slide, js-transition-fade, etc).

Using data attributes is much easier when things get complicated, such as setting numerical values (js-delay-500, etc), but is HTML5. This personally doesn't bother me, or 99% percent of users, but in the past (for doing something similar) I've been contacted by a user who was concerned about their page invalidating with a particular DocType due to the plugin markup. I can't recall entirely why this DocType was required (lost the email), but I think it may have had something to do with some HTTPS payment pages and security validation. I actually think this may have tied in with one of the plugin links not being HTTPS as well. Really vague, I know.

I guess that kind-of poses another question. Is valid markup ever officially required as well?

Appreciate anyone who can enlighten me. Again, I'm all for HTML5, as are most, but with the nature of such things (like Wordpress plugins) it can be important to support a wide range of use cases not to alienate specific users (or at least provide them with alternative options).

Comment: A doctype is needed to prevent quirks mode from being activated. `<!doctype html>` does that. The page does not need to be valid. What matters is if it works in the browser.

Comment: I know why a doctype is needed, asking if a specific doctype in particular is ever required for a particular use-case/situation.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Quirks mode prevention is their only purpose.